# доступ к DigitalOcean по своиму логину

Tags: логирование, digitalocean

Клиент дал логин к DigitalOcean -у и при вводе получил сообщение

> Verify it's you
>
> We've sent a verification code to your email.
>
> Enter the code from the email in the field below.

Емейл явно пошел на мейл владельца логина.
Если мне удастся зайти в систему(получив подтверждающий код от клиента) можно ли (и где) создать логин со своим мейлом, чтобы после заходить под своим логином?

Answer (score 1):

Да, можно сделать свой логин, на который клиент сможет передать права для управления. Для этого им нужно [создать команду](https://cloud.digitalocean.com/settings/team/new) и [далее по инструкции](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/accounts/teams/).